# Can access new gmail api by using GoogleApiClient(Android)?

Tags: android, gmail-api

Is a way to access from android the new gmail api by using GoogleApiClient and get messages from account?
If is possible can someone give me an example or guiding me?
If not what is the best way to get the messages from account by not using imap or smtp.

Comment: Do you looking for this : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java ?

Comment: As per the link the json file should be given as input. How can we give it in android, its unsafe. Isnt it?

Comment: I couldnt get GoogleApiClient working and started using SMTP which is working. Just interested to know why you don't want to use IMAP or SMTP?

Comment: I don't want to use IMAP  because I see on the presentation of the new gmail api that this is more performant and I want to learn about this.

Comment: I think a good start is from Task sample application for android. Isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, the solution was given on Google development site. this is how it can be done , add scopes as "oauth2:" + GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM u can add muliple scopes comma seperated but you have to use oauth2: before the first scope you enter . this is how i call it

```
 new GetAuthTokenTask(MainActivity.this,
            emailId,
            "oauth2:" + GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM)
            .execute();
```

and  this is the code for Async task

```
public class GetAuthTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = GetAuthTokenTask.class.getSimpleName();
    Activity mActivity;
    String mScope;
    String mEmail;

    GetAuthTokenTask(Activity activity, String name, String scope) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mScope = scope;
        this.mEmail = name;
    }

    /**
     * Executes the asynchronous job. This runs when you call execute()
     * on the AsyncTask instance.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String token = fetchAuthToken();
            if (token != null){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Token :" + token);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, " Error Internet Connection :" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected String fetchAuthToken() throws IOException{
        try {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "accountId :" + mEmail);
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
            // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
            // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error UserRecoverableAuthException :" + userRecoverableException);
            userRecoverableException.printStackTrace();
            handleException(userRecoverableException);

        } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
            // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
            // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error GoogleAuthException :" + fatalException);
            fatalException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

add this function to the activity from which you are executing this async task

```
public void handleException(final Exception e) {
    // Because this call comes from the AsyncTask, we must ensure that the following
    // code instead executes on the UI thread.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (e instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) {
                // The Google Play services APK is old, disabled, or not present.
                // Show a dialog created by Google Play services that allows
                // the user to update the APK
                int statusCode = ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) e)
                        .getConnectionStatusCode();
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode,
                        MainActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                dialog.show();
            } else if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                // Unable to authenticate, such as when the user has not yet granted
                // the app access to the account, but the user can fix this.
                // Forward the user to an activity in Google Play services.
                Intent intent = ((UserRecoverableAuthException) e).getIntent();
                startActivityForResult(intent,
                        REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

override this method in the activity calling this Async task

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR)
            && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Receiving a result that follows a GoogleAuthException, try auth again
        // do the task you need to do after user grants permission
    }
}
```

add this static variable to the activity

```
static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR = 1001; // any number
```

Comment: I think this answer does not respond to the question that is being asked. At this time, it doesn't seem like there is any way at all to use the Gmail API by adding the right config to your `GoogleApiClient.Builder#addApi(...)` function. This observation is supported by the existence of [this (unanswered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29636724/1296709), and the fact that I didn't find any evidence of the contrary yet - be it on this site, or the Google developer docs.