# GoogleApiClient.addApi() doesn't support Gmail API

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the following code to get an authentication with the given APIs but the addApi is neither recognizing Gmail as an API or Gmail.API as an API. Because of this I'm getting an Unauthorized 401 going further into the application when trying to retrieve the messages.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Gmail)
                .addScope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY)
                .build();
```

Comment: Did you enable Gmail API in the developers console? Please include the complete error you are getting..

Comment: @SGC he is saying that there is no Gmail.API option in .addAPI(), only Plus.API. I have same problem, in console I added Gmail.API and got Client ID and secret for that but they are no use cause you can connect to/via Plus.API only. I guess I need also Google+.API in console and Client ID and secret for them. Then you really have to figure out the scope you need to use (all scopes here  https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) https://mail.google.com/, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly would be my 1st choice.

Comment: More than 2 years later, it still does not seem like there is a way to use `GoogleApiClient.Builder#addApi(...)` to state that you want to use the Gmail API (or similarly, the Directory API). I have recently spent quite some time researching this, and I did not yet come across anything that suggests Google made these APIs available via the `GoogleApiClient`.